# Load image data for texture (texImage2DTyped?)

Tags: dart, webgl

I found several ways to load an image and use it as a texture. All examples I found use    texImage2D. But according to the [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_web_gl/RenderingContext.html) this method is some what deprecated. Two alternatives stood out to me: texImage2DUntyped or texImage2DTyped. The untyped version can be fed with an ImageElement for the pixel data but I don't know what values I should pass in for the other parameters?

Because I'd like to abstract the html stuff from the actual gl rendering code I'd like a way, I can load the image and pass the data to the rendering code. I think texImage2DTyped would be good here, but I can't find an example how to load an image as TypedData. And again, what are the possible values for the other parameters?

TL:DR: Is there an example for texImage2DUntyped?

Comment: You may take a look how spectre is using the texImage2DTyped function https://github.com/johnmccutchan/spectre

Comment: It looks like the docs are wrong. For example the docs for `texImage2DCanvas` says "it is highly recommended that you use texImage2DUntyped or texImage2DTyped (or for more specificity, the more specialized texImage2DImageData, **texImage2DCanvas**, texImage2DVideo)".  In other words the docs say both use and don't use that function.  In your case you'd want probably want to use `texImage2DImage`.

Comment: That caught my eye also (-: Thats another reason why I posted here I thought someone out there knows the truth.

Comment: texImage2DImage is a solution but I'd like a way I can load the image data and then pass it to the rendering code without a dependency to the html library - if this is possible

Answer (score 2):

There is an open ticket for the documentation issue:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16195

By the way, I'm using both texImage2DTyped and texImage2DImage here:

https://code.google.com/p/negentropia/source/browse/wwwroot/dart/texture.dart

texImage2DTyped --> takes data from a Uint8List

texImage2DImage --> takes data from a ImageElement